# How to align a Remark

Tags: alignment

I have this problem when I printed my latex code:
[image]

I would like to align the "Remark" the same as Definition. I used \theoremstyle and \newtheorem thing but it print like the picture.

Here is my initial code:
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please show your code. Are you adding the Remark inside or outside of the Definition? Difficult to help when we only see an image.

Comment: Have you defined `remark` as a separate theorem-like environment? If not, how is it defined? Please also stae which document class you employ.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments. I edited my first question.

Answer (score 1):

The `amsthm` package provides three pre-defined theorem styles: `theorem`, `definition`, and `remark`. The directive `\theoremstyle{rem}` should be throwing a warning message -- did you notice it?

Either use `\theoremstyle{remark}` if you want the `remark` style for an environment you call `rem`, or use the `definition` theorem style for both `defn` and `rem` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\newtheorem{teo}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition} % optional
\newtheorem{defn}[teo]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[teo]{Remark}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{defn}[$\sigma$-algebras] 
Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set. \dots
\end{defn}

\begin{rem}
If $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathcal{F}$, \dots
\end{rem}

\begin{defn}[Measures and Measurability] 
Let $\Omega\neq\emptyset$ and \dots
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Mico! many thanks for your help and time!!! You rock!